# How to make a nice formated Maven Site Report table from a csv file?

Tags: java, maven, csv, maven-site-plugin

I have a Maven 3.3.9 project, that creates a csv file: `${project.build.directory}/log.csv`. I want to transform the csv content into an table and include it in site reports.

But I do not find any hint for a plugin that can handle this. - So I maybe be on the wrong track or I am just not able to find the right plugin.